# How to add own traffic layer on google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have json like below.

```
[{
    "startnode_lat": "x1",
    "startnode_lng": "y1",
    "endnode_lat": "x11",
    "endnode_lng": "y11",
    "color": "green"
}, {
    "startnode_lat": "x2",
    "startnode_lng": "y2",
    "endnode_lat": "x22",
    "endnode_lng": "y22",
    "color": "red"
}, {
    "startnode_lat": "x3",
    "startnode_lng": "y3",
    "endnode_lat": "x33",
    "endnode_lng": "y33",
    "color": "yellow"
}]
```

How to add this json like traffic layer on google map

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way should be creating your JSON file in accordance with the GeoJSON format:

http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html

After that you will be able to load it in Maps JavaScript API data layer as shown in the following example:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-simple

Hope it helps!